# Passing string in where clause using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How do I use a `PreparedStatement` to pass a string in a `where` clause?

I have tried following lines of code:

```
String sql = "select pass from lbdb_user WHERE username = ? collate latin1_bin";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1,"\""+username+"\"" );
```

It throws the following mysql exception:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Also, a simple google search will reveal how to do it.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (the code shown is incomplete) and the full exception stacktrace

Comment: It looks like you're trying to retrieve the password, which is already wrong. What you should be doing is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LBDB_USER WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASS = ?`, supplying the username and password you were given, and seeing whether there was one or zero results. Let the database do the matching. All of it.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
String username = "Mickey Mouse";
String sql = "select pass from lbdb_user WHERE username = ? ";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, username);
```

I don't know what that collate thingy is.  I would recommend using Unicode and UTF-8 in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, using COLLATE latin1_bin, as what you have posted and it works

```
String lSql = "SELECT lastname FROM contacts WHERE lastname= ? COLLATE latin1_bin ";
PreparedStatement lPreparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(lSql);
lPreparedStatement.setString(1, "andre");
ResultSet lResultSet = lPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
```